# Histogram Equalisation (Image Javascript Beginner)

Tags: javascript, c++, imagej

I am trying to implement the histogram algorithm using ImageJ for a 8bit grayscale image. Below is my code and is not working properly. Please keep in mind I am a beginner.

How should my imageJ code be so that it works???

```
for (i = 0; i <= MaxIntensity&& lut[i] == 0; i++) { 
  min = lut[i+1]; 
} 

for ( i=0; i < 256; ++i )
{
    sum += histo[i];

    lut[i] = sum;
}
```

Comment: You should also tell us in what way it isn't working as expected. Where do you have a problem?

Comment: @BoPersson : It says min = lut[i + 1] out of range so I have not defined the arrays properly. That would be the reason of the error, so can someone tell me what I need to deal with this?

Comment: Closed at the request of the OP who has explained that his algorithm is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

1. First you have to scan the image to search for min/max - search in [0..pixelCount] in OriginalImage, not in the lut[].
2. Then you fill the histogram (lut[] array, you didn't fill it)
3. Then fill the EqualizedImage[k] with (max - min) * (Original[k] - min) / pixelCount; if I'm not making some mistakes.

EDIT (old stuff here)

The 'i' in for() loop definitely goes out of range with the 'i <= MaxIntensity' (MaxIntensity = 255).

```
lut = newArray(256)
...
min = 0; 
for (i = 0; i <= MaxIntensity&& lut[i] == 0; i++) { 
   min = lut[i+1]; 
}
```

It's not clear what you're trying to do with that code, but if you're just looking for the non-zero minimum in the lut[] array, then why not use this:

```
min = 0; 
for (i = 0; i < MaxIntensity ; i++)
{ 
   if(min > lut[i]) { min = lut[i]; }
}
```

The reason to include the "lut[i] == 0" in original loop is not clear.

Comment: Hi, I changed the code as to what you have suggested although there is not change in the image. I am trying to write the code based on the pseudo code that would equalise the histogram

Comment: To equalize you need the min/max values I support.

Comment: look at the code at the buttom of this link http://www.songho.ca/dsp/histogram/histogram.html similar to what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Yes you would need min and max, since it being an 8 bit grayscale image, 0 and 255 are the values I would assume

Comment: Actually, I don't need to normalize this very image :) I'm just trying to help.

Comment: I dont understand? what you mean

Comment: I've added some thought at the beginning of the post. Try searching min/max in the original image. Then calculate the histogram (btw, dump the histogram in the file and try to compare it with something given by the gfx editor like GIMP or Photoshop, if available). And then renormalize the image.